# Facebook Graph Api returns empty array on gorup feed call

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the feed from a closed group which I am an administrator using [facebook Graph Explorer API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), so I followed the instructions in [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/group/feed)

But the response json is just an empty array like this

```
{"data": []}
```

Here is [my request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LlG9.png)

First I gave the token only the permission described in the documentation, then i gave all permissons and yet it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4:

> **Groups API**
>   App Review — All apps, including formerly approved apps, must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the API.

Until you submit your app for review and get it approved, this will only work if you put your app in “dev” mode. As soon as you set it “live”, you will only get an empty result if you did not get your app reviewed yet.

Comment: Even in dev mode, I am getting blank.

Comment: @venins still works fine for me in dev mode. Is the account you are testing with actually an admin of the group?

Comment: ya it's working, I was using friendlist, and it works only for friends who use the same app.